# How Do You Make Your Entire OWN Language Coder? I Tried This.. (doesn't work)

Tags: javascript

I tried to make it all connect but nothing is working.. I am horrible at JavaScript.. It says that it is 'undefined'. I think it is defined..

```
var convert = function (x) {
    alert(dxc(x));

    function dxc(m) {
        stg(m.charAt(0));
    }

    function stg(d) {
        if (d === "d") {
            d = "p";
        }
    }
};

var conversion = prompt("What do you want to translate?");
convert(conversion);
```

Edit: This is just for the idea of the entire thing, I was no where near done..

Comment: `undefined` is "returned" from `stg` which is returned from `dxc` which is passed to `alert` .. also, the title makes no sense and is not fitting of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is just a name that points to a value; when you do `d = "p"`, you're changing what `d` points to, but you changed *only* `d`; the source of `d` (in particular, `m.charAt(0)`) is left unchanged.

You'll have to return the modified string manually:

```
function dxc(m) {
    return stg(m.charAt(0)) + m.substring(1);
}

function stg(d) {
    if (d === "d") {
        return "p";
    }else{
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2103896: `stg` is returning a one-character string. `dxc` is returning a string with the first character replaced with the return value of `stg`. The return value of `dxc` is passed to `alert`. `convert` implicitly returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to `return` the values you want to return

```
var convert = function(x) {
    alert(dxc(x));

    function dxc(m) {
        return stg(m.charAt(0));          
    }
    function stg(d) {
        if (d === "d") {
            d = "p";
        }
        return d;
    }
};

var conversion = prompt("What do you want to translate?");
convert(conversion);
```

Comment: What is the exact importance and definition of returning something in JavaScript? I have mixed thoughts on it.. I thought 'd' represented a local variable, how and why do you take it outside?

Comment: @user2103896 `d` **is** a local variable, but only to its parent scope/function...which is `stg`. If you want to access something outside of a scope, you have to `return` it. At the same time, if you move `d` into a higher scope (like into that of `convert`), it would be accessible by *that* scope. That's why `dxc` and `stg` are both accessible in their scope

Comment: Thank you a lot! That definitely helped.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions aren't returning anything.

Try:

```
var convert = function (x) {
    alert(dxc(x));

    function dxc(m) {
        return stg(m.charAt(0));
    }

    function stg(d) {
        if (d === "d") {
            d = "p";
        }

        return d;
    }
};
```